# Model calls from Laravel transformer class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have been using Transformers(fractal) for transforming the data before it is send as an output for the API call.
So from controller I am calling the transformer class and passing the data like this

```
$data = $this
    ->myModelClass
    ->search($filters);

$data = $this
    ->listTransformer
    ->transform($data);
```

and in the transformer,

```
public function transform($result)
{
    $resource = $this->factory->make($result, function ($item) {

        return [
            'id'               => $item->id,
            'name'             => $item->name,
            'category_name'    => $this->anotherModel->getCategory($item->category_id),
            'revenue'          => $this->anotherModel->getRevenue($item->earnings)
        ];
    });

    $result = $this
        ->manager
        ->createData($resource)
        ->toArray();

    return $result['data'];
}
```

So basically, I am calling models from the transformer. Is this the right way of doing it ?

I have seen another method which uses the includes, but if I have a number of items there in the array, 
which needs to be passed to the model for getting details, I need to write a number of transformers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is a bad practice as it violates the "Single Responsibility" principle of SOLID. Your transformer is no longer just responsible for transforming data, it now also queries data, which then ties it to your data layer, making it "tightly coupled".

There is no harm passing a model object to a transformer, which contains other related models, however the transformer should have one responsibility, transforming data.

Typically I would create a transformer per model, and then have the domain (aggregate) model use the other explicit transformers, this would involve you building an "domain" (aggregate) model **before** passing it to your transformer. This and means any changes to your data layer will have a minimal impact on your transformers.

A working example below:

```
class LeadTransformer extends Transformer implements LeadTransformerInterface {

    /**
     * @var CustomerTransformerInterface
     */
    protected $customerTransformer;

    /**
     * @var EnquiryTypeTransformerInterface
     */
    protected $enquiryTypeTransformer;

    /**
     * @var PlanTransformerInterface
     */
    protected $planTransformer;

    /**
     * @param CustomerTransformerInterface $customerTransformer
     * @param EnquiryTypeTransformerInterface $enquiryTypeTransformer
     * @param PlanTransformerInterface $planTransformer
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerTransformerInterface $customerTransformer, EnquiryTypeTransformerInterface $enquiryTypeTransformer, PlanTransformerInterface $planTransformer)
    {
        $this->customerTransformer = $customerTransformer;
        $this->enquiryTypeTransformer = $enquiryTypeTransformer;
        $this->planTransformer = $planTransformer;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a lead
     *
     * @param array $lead
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform($lead)
    {
        $data = [
            // Do Transformation
        ];

        if($lead->enquiry_type)
        {
            $data['enquiry_type'] = $this->enquiryTypeTransformer->transform($lead->enquiry_type);
        }

        if($lead->customer)
        {
            $data['customer'] = $this->customerTransformer->transform($lead->customer);
        }

        if($lead->plan)
        {
            $data['plan'] = $this->planTransformer->transform($lead->plan);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

In the above example, LeadTransformer has three other transformers injected as dependencies by laravel's IoC Container. When it comes to transforming the data in that related model, that models transformer is used.

This means should I ever need to manipulate the "Customer" model, I have no need to interfere with other aspects of my application, as it's all be abstracted out.

Hope this answers your questions, should you have any follow up questions please comment and I shall do my best to address them

Comment: So if I have to transform enquiry_staus, then should I need to write another class called EnquiryStatusTransformer ?

Comment: Also in my case it is looping through the item and fetching more details for some of them by calling model function. For example, I am calling getCategory function and passing the category_id to get the category name. How we can do this alternatively ?

Comment: Generally, you should prepare a "complete" model ready for transformation before passing it to your transformer. If you're using eloquent, you can eager load all your relationships before passing it to the transformer, removing any need to query within the transformer. Generally a well formed transformer should contain a transform() method and a transformCollection() method, so you could call: `$this->categoryTransformer->transformCollection($list->categories);` Assuming you've eager loaded your categories before passing to the ListTransformer.

Comment: Hi @HappyCoder I have uploaded a sample project to github here: https://github.com/xeeeveee/Laravel-Transformers-Example demonstrating my point on nested transformers, let me know if you have any further questions. :)

Comment: This is super helpful.

Comment: But unfortunately, I am not using Eloquent.

Comment: @HappyCoder Do you have a full code sample you can share? Would be happy to look over it.